# Is it fine if I share a .pfx self signed certificate generated inside my machine with other users to test and use PnPCore SDK

Tags: certificates, azure, self-signed, pfx

We want to develop some Azure functions which use PnPCore SDK. For testing purposes, I registered an Azure app which uses self-signed certificate for authentication.

Now I configured the Azure app registration to only access our SharePoint test site, so it is fine to use self-signed certificate for testing purposes. But I have a question, to be able to test the PNPCore SDK locally, users need to install the self-signed .pfx certificate inside their machines. But I have generated this self-signed certificate from my machine, so is it fine to share this .pfx with other users? Or might this .pfx certificate contain private info from my machine, like the login username and password?

This is the PowerShell code I used to generate the .pfx certificate:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName "SPGPIntegration-Test"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "******" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\LocalMachine\my\7**A -FilePath "C:\cert-Test\SPGPIntegration-Test.pfx" -Password $pwd
Export-Certificate -Cert Cert:\LocalMachine\my\7**A -FilePath "C:\cert-Test\SPGPIntegration-Test.crt"
```